# How to make page border in print CSS for every single page

Tags: html, css, print-css

I have a long HTML to print. Page is ready for printing but I need to border every single page. I added `body { border:2px #666 solid; padding:5px;  }` in CSS code. HTML view is nice but print view is not. Because border-bottom is not showing first page and border-top is not showing all other pages.

I hope, I can explain what I want. I'm searched and still searching for solution. And I think it's easy trick. But stil not found.

Comment: Long time ago, there was an option called `marks`. Unfortunately, its deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/marks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this it will help you : It will make border on full screen.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Border around content</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    #wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      overflow: auto;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      border: 5px solid red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for the first page is ok but there are 3 - 4 pages for print. Others not existing on printing.

Comment: So on other page try to add this code again ... elaborate what you want

Comment: Ok I tried someting and solved my problem. Changed the #wrapper `position:absolute` to `position:fixed`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: And can you upvote my question. Why they giving downvote, I cant understand.

Answer (score 13):

The best way is putting a fixed `div` in a page. The important thing is that you should not put any content inside it. It works seamlessly with multi-pages:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #pageborder {
      position:fixed;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      border: 2px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="pageborder">
  </div>
sdf<br/>
sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>
sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>sdf<br/>
111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>
111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>111<br/>
222<br/>222<br/>222<br/>222<br/>222<br/>222<br/>222<br/>222<br/>222<br/>222<br/>222<br/>222<br/>222<br/>222<br/>222<br/>222<br/>222<br/>222<br/>222<br/>222<br/>222<br/>222<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

By default, the border renders *outside* of the area of the element.

Try adding this to the print CSS:

```
body { box-sizing: border-box; border: 10px solid black; }
```

Hope this helps!

Edit: you can also try making the border bigger, and adding temporarily !important to the box-sizing and border CSS. That sometimes helps me find the source of the trouble.